# Confusion about IBM's Informix documentation for insert statements

Tags: documentation, sql-insert, informix, insert-into

I am currently using `Informix 12.10 FC6`. I have found two pieces of what seem to be contradicting documentation on the `VALUES` clause of an insert statement. Both documents are from `IBM`'s `Informix` documentation. Can anyone explain the difference and why they do not contradict each other. The part that confuses me is one seems to say that expressions cannot be added to the VALUES clause and one does. 
I am looking for some clarification on what I am missing.

Here are the links:

[Link 1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_216.htm)

[Link 2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0132.htm)

Comment: In general, you'll get better responses if you at least identify the information from each that you consider contradicts the other.  One link is to the SQL Tutorial, one is to the SQL Syntax guide.  Between the two, I'd trust the syntax guide more than the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

[Informix SQL Tutorial – Insert rows — Possible column values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_216.htm) — aka 'Link 1' in the question — starts off with the statement:

> The VALUES clause accepts only constant values, not general SQL expressions.

[Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax — INSERT statement — VALUES clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0132.htm) — aka 'Link 2' in the question — is covering the INSERT statement comprehensively, including its use in ESQL/C (Embedded SQL in C) code and in SPL (Stored Procedure Language) code.  It lists more options for what can be used, such as host variables (marked 'ESQL/C only' and 'Informix extension').  It also lists options such as 'Expression' and 'Constant expression'.

The tutorial is over-simplifying what's allowed.

The syntax manual is more thorough and is more correct.  There are still limits on what you can use in a VALUES clause, but they're more expansive than the simple description in the tutorial indicates — but it is a tutorial.  When it comes down to the details, each value in the VALUES clause is a single value, possibly the result from a function evaluation or some other expression.  There are severe limits on the form of `SELECT` statement that can be used, but they can be used:

```
create table x(i integer not null primary key);
insert into x values(1024);
insert into x values((select max(i)+1 from x));
```

The parentheses around the `SELECT` are needed as well as the parentheses around the VALUES clause, so the doubled parentheses are necessary.